# where and how to give Auto updation of database column

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table with following attributes `name`, `price`, `start_date`, `end_date`. Here `start_date` and `end_date` denotes the date from when to when does that price for product exists. Upon expiry of the `end_date` I need the `price` column for that particular row to go 0. Is there any way i can implement the same? Database is MySQL and I'm using PHP as server side scripting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not automatically. You will have to do this manually by performing an `UPDATE` statement like below. You can as well configure to run this periodically as SQL Job

```
update pricetbl
set price = 0
where end_date = now();
```

You can as well configure an [Event](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html) for this purpose (a sample)

```
delimiter |

CREATE EVENT updatePrice_daily
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 DAY
    DO
      BEGIN
       UPDATE pricetbl SET price = 0 WHERE end_date = NOW();
      END |

delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a view:

```
create view v_pricetbl as
    select (case when end_date > now() then 0 else price end) as price,
           start_date, end_date
    from atable;
```

If you use a view for access to the table, then the column automatically adjusts to the current time.  Otherwise, you would need to schedule an event to modify the date -- and there would necessarily be a lag between the end date and time, when the query will be out-of-date.